# Sorting an Array so that the highest value is ran first

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

In the method petInteraction() I want to sort the pet by the emotionlevel when the code is ran, this is so that the user can choose which pet to take care of first. At the moment i've included a new method sort(), but it's causing an error.

I'm using eclipse and the error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [I cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
at AlienPetSort.sort(AlienPetSort.java:46)
at AlienPetSort.main(AlienPetSort.java:13)
```

Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: Which error is it causing?

Comment: I've updated the main post

Comment: You should really introduce a class Pet that holds all pet attributes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private static int[][] EmotionalState = new int[2][3];
.
.
    Arrays.sort(EmotionalState);
```

Given the above lines. Arrays.sort takes a one-dimensional array as a parameter and you are passing in a two-dimensional array.

Answer (score 2):

What's going on is that you're trying to run `Arrays.sort(EmotionalState);`, but `EmotionalState` is a two-dimensional array. You can use a `Comparator` to sort that two-dimensional array, but I don't believe that `Arrays` supports more than one dimension -- here's an example I found from a quick Google search: http://techthinking.net/2010/02/sorting-two-dimensional-string-array-using-java/.

Looking at your code design really quick, I think you'd be well off to define a Pet object and give them specific emotional state values, rather than try to maintain it all in a two-dimensional array. Especially if you plan on continue adding more to your code, it's well worth at least a small refactor job!

Answer (score 0):

You can't sort two dimensional array with plain `Arrays.sort`. To sort two dimensional array use `Comparator`,

```
private static int[][] EmotionalState = new int[2][3];    
   ....

  Arrays.sort(EmotionalState, new Comparator<int[]>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(int[] o1, int[] o2) {
            return o1[0] - o2[0];
        }
  });
```